# MYSQL DAYNAME() issue

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in a database with the columns

```
d_monday, d_tuesday, d_wednesday, d_thursday, d_friday, d_saturday, d_sunday
```

The values for these are either 0 or Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday etc depending on the day.

in my select statement I'm using

```
SELECT * from DEALS WHERE d_monday=DAYNAME(NOW()) OR d_tuesday=DAYNAME(NOW())
```

to find out whether the day name matches up with todays day, if it does then it returns results otherwise it doesn't display anything.

For some reason it's returning results when I haven't any value set for that specific day.

Any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: Why you don't use datetime fields? Why so complicated?

Comment: I tried datetime fields although I dont need it to relate to specific times only days Monday through Sunday.

Comment: you have to write 8 condition in `WHERE`..did u heard the word `'optimization'` and `normalizaion`?

Comment: I'm very sorry it seems one of my fields was set as an INT instead of varchar. Sorry for such a silly question :(

Comment: I wonder what's wrong with using _just one_ field `deal_day` of ENUM ('Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed',...) type, if you're so against DATETIME?

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to pick the field using a PHP string

```
$day = "d_". date('l'); //lowercase L is full day name
$SQL = "SELECT $day FROM DEALS WHERE [...]";
```

I'm guessing a bit but would this not take you in the right direction?

Or something like this

```
$day = date('l'); //lowercase L is full day name
$SQL = "SELECT * from DEALS WHERE d_monday='$day' OR d_tuesday='$day' ";
```

It seems to me that you might want

```
$day = date('l'); //lowercase L is full day name
$SQL = "SELECT * from DEALS WHERE d_$day='$day'";
```

The format seems a bit messed up or maybe I just got the wrong end of the stick.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Consider removing your seven columns for the days of week and adding a separate table `DealDays` with a foreign key referencing `Deals`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE DealDays (
  DealDayID int NOT NULL,
  DealID int NOT NULL,
  DayName varchar(10) NOT NULL,  /* or, perhaps, enum ('Sunday', 'Monday', …) */
  PRIMARY KEY (DealDayID),
  FOREIGN KEY (DealID) REFERENCING Dels (DealID),  /* or whatever is Deal PK's name */
  UNIQUE (DealID, DayName)  /* to make sure you can't add the same day twice per deal */
);
```

Then you would be able to find deals for the present day like this:

```sql
SELECT
  d.DealID,
  d.whatever,
  …
FROM Deals d
INNER JOIN DealDays dd ON d.DealID = dd.DealID
WHERE dd.DayName = DAYNAME(NOW())
```

Answer (score 0):

your query works fine. May be problem is in your data type of column(s) please check that.

My suggestion is that for that purpose you can use only one column so that your database is optimised.